# was or were in conditional clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

I'd like to know whether "was" or "were" should be used in the **main clause** of the following:

> If there were a 200-story office building without an elevator, those whose office **was** / **were** on the 180th floor would climb many steps each day.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["If something was" vs "If something were"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127745/if-something-was-vs-if-something-were)

Comment: @user070221 No, you have no idea about the nature of the question. My question concerns whether a verb in the main clause should be subjunctive or indicative.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify it then.

Comment: @ColleenV I already included "in the **main clause** of the following" in the question. Only those who refuse to consider the question carefully would think it is a duplicate of an earlier one.

Answer (score 3):

The verb should be "were", but the reason is that "those whose office..." is not correct. Unless all of the people were sharing one office (pretty sure that's not what you mean to say), you should say, "offices" [plural].

So your sentence should be:

> If there were a 20-story office building, those whose *offices were* on the 18th floor would climb many steps each day.

Comment: What if the people did share an office?

Comment: If the people working on the 18th floor were all sharing one office on that floor, "office" would be singular, and you should use "was": "If there were a 20-story office building, those whose *office was* on the 18th floor would climb many steps each day."

Comment: The tricky part is this: if it is factual, why is it not in the indicative, i.e. "is"?
If it is conditional, why is it not "were"?

Comment: In the "office-sharing" sentence, "whose office was..." is a phrase modifying "those". Since my ears are numb from all the "office(s)" business, consider the following, "If there *were* a tall building, and a man who is/was/were afraid of heights *were* to get a job there ...." Indicative "is" is OK. "Were" sounds weird, maybe because the fear of heights is a *real* attribute (of a *hypothetical* person). My choice would be "was" [past tense??]. I don't really know why. Perhaps my answer is wrong, but it still sounds OK to me.

Comment: @Apollyon Since you got me thinking, I am starting to feel "If there were a 20-story office building, those whose office *is* on the 18th floor would ..." [indicative "is"] might be acceptable (provided all those people shared the office), ... but I still prefer "was".

Comment: @Apollyon You already use the subjunctive in the main clause of the sentence: *If there* ***were***. You don't need to keep repeating its use in all remaining parts of the sentence.